# Google Cloud storage: Grant permission to OAuth 2.0 client

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I try to download a file from a google cloud drive bucket via the REST. But if I use the access_token of the oAuth 2.0 client which I have created I get "Insufficient Permission" as an error (It works with the access toke of my googel account).

So, where in the cloud platform I can grant the oAuth2 client access to the bucket from where I want to download the file?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You're most likely missing the step where you request the right scopes when requesting your OAuth2.0 access token. Please look at the [supported scopes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes) with Google Cloud Storage APIs. Access tokens typically expire in 60 minutes and you will need to use a refresh token to get a new access token when it expires.

Please read the [Google Cloud Storage Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) page for detailed information.

> ### [Scopes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes)
>
> Authorization is the process of determining what permissions an
>   authenticated identity has on a set of specified resources. OAuth uses
>   [scopes](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#oauth_scopes) to determine if an authenticated identity is authorized.
>   Applications use a credential (obtained from a user-centric or
>   server-centric authentication flow) together with one or more scopes
>   to request an access token from a Google authorization server to
>   access protected resources.
>
> For example, application A with an access
>   token with `read-only` scope can only read, while application B with an
>   access token with `read-write` scope can read and modify data. Neither
>   application can read or modify access control lists on objects and
>   buckets; only an application with `full-control` scope can do so.

### [Authentication in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/)

Google Cloud services generally provides 3 main modes of authentication:

- [End User Account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user) - here you authenticate as the end user directly using their google account or an [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) access token. When [requesting an access token](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#requesting_access_to_user_resources), [you will need to provide the scopes](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#requesting_access_to_user_resources) which determine which APIs are accessible to the client using that access token.

  OAuth2.0 credentials - if granted the right scope, can access the user's private data. In addition, [Cloud IAM lets you control fine grained permissions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#granting_and_limiting_access_to_project_resources) by granting roles to this user account.
- [Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#service_accounts) - here you [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) which is associated with a specific GCP project (and billed to that project thereby). These are mainly used for automated use from your code or any of the Google Cloud services like Compute Engine, App Engine, Cloud Functions, etc. You can create service accounts using Google Cloud IAM.

  Each service account has an associated email address (you specify when creating the service account) and you will need to grant appropriate roles for this email address for your Cloud Storage buckets/objects. These credentials if granted the right roles can access the user's private data.
- [**API keys**](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) - here you get an encrypted string which is associated with a GCP project. It is supported only by very few Google Cloud APIs and it is not possible to restrict the scope of API keys (unlike service accounts or OAuth2.0 access tokens).